# Azure Devops Build Complete Notifications aren't firing

Tags: azure-devops, notifications, bitbucket, devops

Azure DevOps "Build Complete" Notifications aren't firing when there is auto-trigger fires the build because of a commit in the bitbucket git repo. The build and release complete with no issues but the email notifications don't go to all at all to the team members. The end goal trying to achieve is to send an email to the administrator and the user who has checked the code in the bitbucket repo.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi SNew, Does my answer help? If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Supported subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops), we can subscribe notification of Build completed, as below. Thus only members of artifact-demo Team can receive notification which meet the filter criteria.
[image]

From your snapshot, it is [out-of-the-box (OOB) or default subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/oob-built-in-notifications?view=azure-devops#out-of-the-box-oob-or-default-subscriptions), and will send notifications to all subscribers, by default. Thus members of Dev Team can receive notification.
[image]

Therefore, if you have a [CI pipeline for bitbucket repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers), and want to send an email to the administrator and the user (we call it contributor) who has checked the code in the bitbucket repo via Azure DevOps notification service, please make sure that the administrator and the contributor are members of Dev team, so they will get build completed notification. Otherwise, they need to subscribe such notification via [Personal notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#add-a-custom-subscription)s or [Team notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-global-organization-notifications?view=azure-devops#create-an-email-subscription)

**Update**>>If you want to only send notifications to the administrator and contributor, you could choose "**Custom email address**" and then set up multiple subsciptions.
[image]
Or the administrator and contributor can subscribe this notification via [Personal notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-your-personal-notifications?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-account-enabled#add-a-custom-subscription).
[image]

BTW, if some users doesn't want to receive such notifications, they can manually [unsubscribe it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/unsubscribe-default-notification?view=azure-devops).

**Update2**>>Using custom email address will send email to specific user. And if you have 20 members, there might be too many subscriptions, you could consider to add these 20 members to a new group/team(NotificatoinTeam), and then just need to subscribe this notification for this group and choose "Members of NotificatoinTeam", so everything is done. If there is new member wants to get this notification, just adds them to this group/team. Also if some members don't  want to get this notification, just remove them from this NotificatoinTeam group/team.

**Update3**>>You could use this predefined variable `Build.RequestedForEmail` to get the contributor's email. See: [Build variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) for more details.

Comment: Right now all the members of the Team are getting build complete and failure but I am not seeing any option where it only sends an email to the administrator and contributor i.e who committed the code. In your top two screen shots, I don't see an option configure contributor and administrator. @edward-han-msft

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: I am seeing 4 snapshots in your response and you are referring 3rd and 4th snapshot with a custom email address, are you saying if we have 20 members then I have to create 20 custom subscriptions with each of their email address. See this picture https://www.screencast.com/t/uzewyH2If and I have added one user email address how would another developer will get notification when subscription is hardcoded to one particular User. I am missing something

Comment: Using custom email address will send email to specific user. And if have 20 members, there might be too many subscriptions, you could consider to add these 20 members to a new group/ team, and then just need to subscribe this notification for this group and choose "Members of *** Team", so it is done. If there is new member wants to get this notification, just adds them to this group/team. Also if one member doesn't want to get this notification, just remove them from this group/team.

Comment: I have set up as per your instructions but all members are getting the email notification and the goal here is only the contributor should get the email i.e who has checkin the commit in the bitbucket repo

Comment: As my comment says that you could add those who needs to receive this notification to the new group, so if some users who don't need to subscribe it, please remove them from this group. Or you could use this 3rd-party free extension: [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask), so you can specify who receive this notification.

Comment: I mean to say all members in the group need to receive the notification only when they commit a code change. Say we have 10 users user 1, user 2 ....user 10 and if user 2 committed a code then the notification should go admin and user 2 and NOT user 3 or user1. Currently all users user 1 to user 10 are getting notification. I am sorry if I am conveying the message correctly.

Comment: I see this comment in this link and this might by design https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/notification-not-sent-for-triggered-ci-builds-from/421119 "These roles are based on Azure DevOps identities. This works great if the source repository is in Azure Repos but doesn't work well for repositories that are not in Azure DevOps like BitBucket. The user who triggered the build is a BitBucket user that doesn't map to a Azure DevOps identity since they are different systems."

Comment: Yeah, it should be by design. And you could try to use this extension: Send Email, so you can specify the user using variable who receive this notification is the one triggers it.

Comment: Any thought of variable to pull the email id of the last git commit user to use send email extension. Right now I am not seeing any variable?

Comment: Please see my answer>>Update3. Also you could use API: [Builds - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get build details to find the contributor's information.

Comment: $Build.RequestedForEmail variable is not pulling user email id from bitbucket git commit. It comes as empty, it comes with correct value if the repo in azure devops.

Comment: These pre-defined variables are automatically set by the system and read-only. Your bitbucket users do not automatically get access to Azure Pipelines. Azure Pipelines is unaware of bitbucket identities. For this reason, there is no way to configure Azure Pipelines to automatically notify users of a build failure or a PR validation failure using their bitbucket identity and email address.

Comment: @SNew Did you ever find a way to make this work? I didn't find any variable I could use to create some sort of mapping between GitHub and Azure DevOps users.